# Initial authentication: sending `auth.sendCode` and receiving `msg_container` instead of `auth.SentCode` in python

Tags: python, authentication, telegram

I've downloaded a CLI version of Telegram ( https://telegram.org/ ). the Not-So-Complete version of that CLI interface was downloaded from: 
https://github.com/griganton/telepy

Now the authentication all in all works fine but there is 0 actual functionality going on.

so i changed a little bit the JASON-Scheme and added the required functionality i need for initial authentication

```
{'id': '1988976461',
 'method': 'sendCode',
 'params': [{'name': 'phone_number', 'type': 'string'},
            {'name': 'sms_type', 'type': 'int'},
            {'name': 'api_id', 'type': 'int'},
            {'name': 'api_hash', 'type': 'string'},
            {'name': 'lang_code', 'type': 'string'}],
 'type': 'SentCode'}
```

as written in the documentation
https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendCode

Now after i've dont that, by the documentation it seems like after sending a message requesting for an SMS code i should receive  `auth.SentCode` with the hex code in the beginning of the packet `0xEFED51D9`, but instead i am receiving  as a response from the server, something of type `msg_container73f1f8dc` which doesnt seem connected what so ever to my request.

This all in all seems very annoying and odd, i have no clue what might cause that all in all i followed to documentation and tried to implement as requested.

The packet i am sending look fine, and i actually get the SmsCode to my Phone.. but the response i get is bad \ unclear for some reason.

I'm calling the function implemented in the JSON like this:

```
auth = Session.method_call('sendCode', phone_number=PHONE_NUMBER, sms_type=0, api_id=MY_API_ID, api_hash=MY_API_HASH, lang_code="en")
```

so it is functioning.. but i need the 
`phone_code_hash`.  Please note that for some reason the documentation of Telegram itself is weird as well. Looking at a query example they gave, the numbers just dont match up to what the documentation say (quoted from their documentation):

**Query example:**

```
(auth.sendCode "79991234567" 1 32 "test-hash" "en")
=
(auth.sentCode
  phone_registered:(boolFalse)
  phone_code_hash:"2dc02d2cda9e615c84"
)

d16ff372 3939370b 33323139 37363534 00000001 00000020 73657409 61682d74 00006873 e77e812d
=
2215bcbd bc799737 63643212 32643230 39616463 35313665 00343863 e12b7901
```

taken from here: https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendCode

the expected first DWORD on each part should be different..
for example: `768d5f4d` instead of `d16ff372`..

So what am i missing?

some reference (for some reason it doesnt let me post this if i dont put it as a code section)

```
https://core.telegram.org/constructor/auth.sentCode
https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/service_messages
https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendCode
```

Comment: I think the unrecognized constructor IDs are from older versions of those functions/objects. Looking at a schema from Layer 2 [here](https://github.com/datamachine/tltc/blob/master/schemas/telegram/layer2.tl#L137), we see that the old versions were `auth.sendCode#d16ff372 phone_number:string sms_type:int api_id:int api_hash:string = auth.SentCode` and `auth.sentCode#2215bcbd phone_registered:Bool phone_code_hash:string = auth.SentCode`. In my experience, the old response at least is still in use on the test servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was bad handling of the socket.. the server just sent two packets.

The first packet was some `Message_Service` and the second packet was the data i actually want..

Its weird because it didnt say anything about these messages in the documentation

Comment: can you put an example how wrote code? i not found sample.

Answer (score 0):

Telegram most times would pack messages into a msg_container.

For example you might get a Msg_acks for previous messages along with the expected response of your last message.

Your best bet would be to setup your code to handle cases of received containers, check the count of items in the container then loop through the received messages, passing different message types to appropriate handlers.

Also note that you might get an rpc_response which contains a gzipped message, in that case you would need to unzip, and then process your message content which could also contain collection of messages

cheers